# Converting HTML to show link URLs using PHP

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Is it possible to convert the first block a text to the second block of text using PHP?  If so, how?  Thanks

```
<div>
 <p>Some text & a <a href="http://abc.com/index.php?x=123&y=abc">link</a>. Done</p>
 <p>More text & a <a href="http://abc.com/index.php?x=123&y=abc">link</a>. Done</p>
</div>


<div>
 <p>Some text & a <strong>link</strong> <i>(http://abc.com/index.php?x=123&y=abc)</i>. Done</p>
 <p>More text & a <strong>link</strong> <i>(http://abc.com/index.php?x=123&y=abc)</i>. Done</p>
</div>
```

EDIT.  Per Andy's recommendation, looking at something like the following.  Still struggling on the converting of links, but it looks like a good start.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);   //Temporarily disable errors resulting from improperly formed HTML
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($array['message_text']);
$a = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($a as $link)
{
    //Where do I go from here?
}
$array['message_text'] = $doc->saveHTML();
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```

Comment: Please look at using a proper DOM parser.  Regular expressions are *not* a good solution except when dealing with very narrow test cases.  See http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Thank you Andy.  I am thinking something like what I have in my edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your HTML is malformed, as `&` needs to be encoded as its HTML entity `&amp;`. Fixing this gives us:

```
$html = '<div>
 <p>Some text &amp; a <a href="http://abc.com/index.php?x=123&amp;y=abc">link</a>. Done</p>
 <p>More text &amp; a <a href="http://abc.com/index.php?x=123&amp;y=abc">link</a>. Done</p>
</div>';
```

From here, you shouldn't use a regex. It is incredibly brittle and not meant for parsing HTML. Instead, you can use PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) class to parse the HTML, extract the `<a>` tags, pull the information you want from them, create the new HTML elements, and insert them into the appropriate place.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach( $xpath->query( '//a') as $a) {
    $strong = $doc->createElement( 'strong', $a->textContent);
    $i = $doc->createElement( 'i', htmlentities( $a->getAttribute('href')));
    $a->parentNode->insertBefore( $strong, $a);
    $a->parentNode->insertBefore( $i, $a);
    $a->parentNode->removeChild( $a);
}
```

This [prints](http://viper-7.com/OZb5AQ):

```
<p>Some text &amp; a <strong>link</strong><i>http://abc.com/index.php?x=123&amp;y=abc</i>. Done</p> 
<p>More text &amp; a <strong>link</strong><i>http://abc.com/index.php?x=123&amp;y=abc</i>. Done</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I will go over this in detail.

Comment: DOMXPath().  Never used that before.  Regardless, your solution works perfect.  I will definitely study up on it so I know why it works..

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use Regular Expressions.

```
$newHtml = preg_replace(/<a[\s\w"'=\t\n]*href="(.*?)"[\s\w"'=\t\n]*>(.*?)<\/a>/i, "<strong>${2}</strong> <i>${1}</i>", $html);
```

You can see the regex [here](http://rubular.com/r/DKx2AUoaAZ)

Comment: That regex only works for that very specific block of text.  OP needs to use a general DOM parser.

Comment: Thanks Gosu.  I will give it a try, but will also explore Andy's recommendations.

Comment: Regex works in this case, it will replace all links, of any HTML, it won't parse the html, it wont see if its malformed or not, but it works, markdown works this way.